# spring websocket with spring security start failed with "No bean named 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' is defined'

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-websocket

spring boot version 1.3.0 release.

the error log is

> 13:00:50.888 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application
>   startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' is defined  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.afterSingletonsInstantiated(AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.java:222)
>   ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   com.d2js.platform.manager.Main.main(Main.java:28) [classes/:na]

my websocket config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private final TeacherMonitorHandler teacherMonitorHandler = null;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(teacherMonitorHandler, "/websocket/teacherMonitor");
    }
}
```

websocket security config class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.anyMessage().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

WebSocket Security is for the STOMP sub-protocol and relies on the STOMP Broker Configuration.

You have to change your `@EnableWebSocket` to the `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` and go ahead with the `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` configuration.

You don't need `WebSocketConfigurer` in that case, by the way.